# how to stop replace function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, regexp-replace

I have a very big string (> 2mln chars).
And I need to replace the text in this string, but this works very slowly.
How I can stop the replacer function if `offset > 65535`?

```
let inReg = MyRegExp();
let str = "very big string....";
str = str.replace(inReg, (match, p1, p2, offset, string) => {
  if (offset > 65535) {
    return myConvertFunc(match);
  } else {
    //How i can stop replacer?
  }
  return match; //this did not stop the replacer function
});
```

Comment: Now i replace substr оf str, but i think there is a better way STR = myReplace(STR.substr(0, 65535)) + STR.substr(65535);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Throw an error in the callback (then wrap the call in a try/catch block)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You could test the offset and just return the original text if it was `> 65535`, but the search would still continue past that point and your callback would still get called.

Instead, isolate the part you want to do the change in:

```
const segmentLength = 65536;
str = str.substring(0, segmentLength).replace(myConvertFunc) +
        str.substring(segmentLength);
```

On the face of it, that seems insane — creating two new strings, one of them a copy of 2M characters! But modern JavaScript engines are very smart about strings (which, being immutable, offer a lot of opportunity for optimization). It's likely any good JavaScript engine would reuse, not copy, the contents of the two strings created via `substring` above, sharing the underlying character array with the original.

Comment: Darn it, I could swear there's a good article on https://v8.dev about how V8 handles strings intelligently (particularly regarding substrings), but I can't find it. :-(